# Парсинг html при помощи php

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, parse

Вот код на сайте который я хочу получить:

```
<span class="adPage__content__price-feature__prices__price__currency" itemprop="priceCurrency" content="€"> € </span>
```

Я не использую для этого библиотеки, ненадо закрывать вопрос и заставлять меня их использовать.

Вот код php:

```
preg_match("/(?<=itemprop=\"priceCurrency\"\ content=\").*?(?=\>)/",$ec,$matches_curr);
```

UPD.

```
preg_match("/(?<=itemprop=\"priceCurrency\"\ content=\").*?(?=\"\>)/",$ec,$matches_curr);
```

Он выдаёт мне €"

А мне нужно чтобы он мне выдавал € без "

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: внесите закрывающуюся кавычку в регулярное выражение

Comment: @ArchDemon я внёс, и выдаёт теперь так: €" > €

Comment: И как увидеть что вы сделали? В вопросе до сих пор изначальный вариант? Отредактируйте вопрос

Comment: @ArchDemon изменил

Comment: да все вроде нормально в исправленном варианте. выводит что надо.

Comment: @teran в этом "вроде" и есть проблема, выводит так как я показал выше(

Comment: в выводе значит что-то добавляется. приведенный вами код дает только 1 символ

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае необходимо добавить закрывающуюся кавычку в регулярное выражение, чтобы аттрибут `content` закрыть (как было сказано в комментариях).

`/(?<=itemprop=\"priceCurrency\"\ content=\").*?(?=\"\>)/`

Таким образом можно достать значение из самого аттрибута.

```php
preg_match("/(?<=itemprop=\"priceCurrency\"\ content=\").*?(?=\"\>)/",$ec,$matches_curr);
```

Проверить можно здесь:
[пример](https://paiza.io/projects/UHnoF2yjNRjDXmn_oi8HUw)

Возвращается массив с одним значением `[0] => €`

Comment: не помогло, всё так же вылезает €" > €

Comment: @Phoz могу попросить пример кода, как это выглядит на paiza.io, который показывает ваш результат?
https://paiza.io/en/projects/new и обязательно запустить код, чтобы ссылка сгенерировалась.

Comment: Максимум, что могу посоветовать в этом случае, раз уж у нас в конце лишные символы, то изменить lookahead: `/(?<=itemprop=\"priceCurrency\"\ content=\").*?(?=\")/`. В этом случае он должен будет остановится на первой закрывающей кавычке.